# Feature to automatically apply Master Page

Tags: master-page

I have a custom master page applied to my site collection. When i create a new sub site, it doesn't come with this custom master page applied to it. I can always go to /_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx on my root site and check the options "Reset all subsites to inherit this Site Master Page setting" and it will apply the same master to every single subsite.

I'm trying to make a feature that automatically does that when i create a new subsite. Is that possible to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a feature, with event receiver

```
public class CustomFeatureReceiver : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiver {
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite("")) {
            using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("")) {
                string url += "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.main.master";
                web.CustomMasterUrl = url;
                web.MasterUrl = url;
                web.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create another feature and staple your first feature to the site definition

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861862(office.12).aspx

3) Or create a custom site definition with your feature

Comment: How do you set it in a custom site definition? Would it be in the Onet.xml - under <Configuration> element. I see there is a MasterUrl attribute, but removing that attrib doesn't inherit the parent's masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the master page gallery in SharePoint Designer you should able to set the default master page in your site, which I think should set all newly created subsites to use that master page.

Comment: James are you sure you can set the default master page in SP Designer.If yes can you please elaborate? Thanks